# Unity LWPR does not see some layers

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2D Unity project with two cameras: [the main one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1WCT.png) and [one designed for parallax effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXcQa.png).
After I installed LWPR for setting lights the second camera stopped showing its layer in game.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practice of rendering two cameras at the same time as you are describing, "camera stacking", is not currently supported on LWRP or URP. There is some [discussion about adding support for it again](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-do-camera-stacking-in-lwrp.795297/).

You could try using a camera to render onto a render texture and display that as your background.

For the 2D light, it is present but is greyed out. You should be able to enable experimental feature use in the player settings for the project.